# formula to convert rad to rev?

Tags: physics

I spent ten minutes googling and can't find it anywhere.

What is the formula to convert a  rev to rad?

What is the formula to convert a  rad to rev?

I think the first is 1 rev = 2 pi * rad and the second is 1 rad = 2pi / rev

Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps if you use the full terms:  radian and revolution.   You would discover that there are $2 \pi$ radians in a full circle.  It is true that 1 revolution is $2 \pi $ radians.  The other direction is $1$ radian is $\frac 1{2 \pi}$ revolution.  In the second the revolution should be in the numerator.